# Caption for each splitted longtable

Tags: captions, longtable

I have a `longtable` and I am trying to get a caption for each new page with this:

```
\begin{longtable}{p{.10\textwidth}|p{.67\textwidth}|p{.13\textwidth}}
    \hline
    A & B & C\\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \caption[My Caption]{Caption}
    \endfoot
    a & b & c \\
    a & b & c \\
    a & b & c \\
    a & b & c \\
    a & b & c \\
    a & b & c \\
    a & b & c \\
    a & b & c \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Now I want that each table caption if it is split gets an additional number, like:

```
Table 1.1-1 for the first page
and
Table 1.1-2 for the second page where the table occurs
```

Also in the list of tables there should be two entries

Comment: What is the typographic or semantic purpose of assigning varying numbers to captions of constructs, such as `longtable`, that can span more than one page? Do the longtables have different meanings before and after a page break? Do you intend to be able to cross-reference page 1 of Table 1.1 separately from page 2 (and pages 3, 4, ...)?

Comment: To be honest I just think this looks much better in an paper. It looks better when every table even if it's just on another page is named and additionally has a caption.

Comment: I'd say that if the tabular material on different pages is sufficiently different so as to merit giving them separate captions, by all means do so. Having different captions immediately makes it clear to the readers that the different tables have different contents. If, on the other hand, it's just a matter of some tabular material being too long to fit on a single page, giving separate captions can create the false (and presumably unwanted) impression that there's no unity of substance across pages. In such cases, it generally suffices to provide a header such as "Table xx, continued".